# Google Analytics wrong landing pages?

Tags: google-analytics

These days, i login to google analytics and all my landing pages is wrong URL.

here's example:

> /forum/iphone-3gs/123/topic-title/http://mydomainname.com

and i click on icon to go to this link, not found.
these days, my site search traffic is going down.

what's wrong with google analytics, google or my site?!

Comment: Please specify the things that you might have changed which result in this.

Are you passing parameters to your `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview','myParameter'])`?

Comment: or `pageTracker._trackPageview('myParameter')` in  the old version?